# .htaccess Redirect all pages to one page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

htaccess snippets to redirect all pages to one page but none of them are working for me.

I need `olddomain.com` , `olddomain.com/pricing` , `olddomain.com/about` , etc all to point to `newdomain.com`.

So `olddomain.com/pricing` shout **not** go to new `domain.com/pricing`.
It should just go to `newdomain.com`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whenever you ask questions, please make use of the preview to check if it is readable. Without formatting the urls so that they will stand out, it is hard to determine what is url and what part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go in the htaccess in your old domain root. If they are **not** on the same server you don't need the `RewriteCond` line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Try this and let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing simpler then that.

If it are different webservers, you can write this on the old ones:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

- `^(.*)$` means everything
- `http://www.newdomain.com` is the target

If it is still the same webserver

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com [L,R=301]
```

It is pretty the same, but you have the condition, that the host is not `newdomain.com`.

Answer (score 4):

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/*  http://www.yourdomain.com/WHATEVER
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/OLD/*  http://www.yourdomain.com/WHATEVER
```